# How can I write a python code faster so that is passes the long given test cases?

Tags: python

```py
def solution(worth,target):
    limit=0

    count=0
    if target>sum(worth):
        return -1
    for buck in worth:
        if limit<target:
            limit+=buck
            count+=1
        
    return count

T=int(input())
worth=list(map(int,input().split()))
Q=int(input())
answer=[]
for i in range(Q):
    target=int(input())
    answer.append(solution(worth,target))
    
for i in answer:
    print(i)
```

## I want to omit something in this code so that it generates faster output.

- T is the number of transactions made in a day
- next line has T integers as input i.e  It is worth of each transaction made
- Next line has Q queries
- Next q lines, the target set for each day

Comment: better to give an example so that we can reproduce the case.

Comment: if you wait for user input every query, the speed speed wont improve...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with sample input and output

Comment: ```pythonTransactions T : 5 
Worth of each transaction T integers : 1 2 1 3 4 
The no of queries Q =3 
Next Q lines contain an integer each representing the daily target.
4
2
10
The output for each Target
3
2
5```

Comment: ```Transactions T : 5 
Worth of each transaction T integers : 1 2 1 3 4 
The no of queries Q =3 
Next Q lines contain an integer each representing the daily target.
4
2
10  
The output for each Target
3
2
5   ```

Answer (score 0):

An examples would be nice but two things: Currently you go through all transactions for every query (twice actually since you use the sum command each time). Collect the queries first since you don't give outputs before having all of them anyway.  Then sort the queries by size, smallest first. Then when summing up the transactions you can do the queries in one go by answering each when its value is reached. All remaining ones can be answered with -1 without needing the sum. (If you need the output in the right order simply safe the order.)

The second thing is that once the last query has been fulfilled, end the loop, no need to go through all remaining items. Whether that comes up depends on the queries of course.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution would be to sort a cumulative sum version of the worth array and use bisection to directly find the number of transaction for each query.  See accumulate in the itertools module and bisect_right in the bisect module.

A simpler (but not as efficient) improvement would be to compute the total worth once before the Q loop and pass it as a `totalWorth` parameter to the `solution` function.  Using the `totalWorth` parameter instead of `sum(worth)` in the `target>sum(worth)` condition would save significant time if worth has many entries.